# Echo printing variables in a completely wrong order

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to create a string with a query that will be save / send to another location, this string contains different variables.

The issue that I am having is that the echo of the variables are completely upside down and mix.

See code below:

```
tokenID=$(docker exec -ti $dockerContainerID /bin/sh -c "cat /tempdir/tokenfile.txt")
serverName="asdasd"
attQuery="$tokenID $serverName"
agentRegQuery="$./opt/mule/bin/amc_setup -H $attQuery"

echo TOKEN ID $tokenID
echo SERVER NAME $serverName
echo $attQuery
echo $agentRegQuery
```

Find below the output I am receiving:

```
TOKEN ID 29a6966f-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407
SERVER NAME asdasd
 asdasdf-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407
 asdasdmule/bin/amc_setup -H 29a6966f-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407
```

Comment: What the value of tokenIDString?

Comment: Sorry, Just copied the wrong line, fixed now, it should be tokenID

Comment: declare -p tokenID

output --->

"eclare -- tokenID="29a6966f-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407

Comment: Examine all the variable using `declare -p var` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a carriage return character at the end of the `tokenID` variable, probably because /tempdir/tokenfile.txt is in DOS/Windows format (lines end with carriage return+linefeed), not unix (lines end with just linefeed). When you print `tokenID` by itself, it looks ok, but if you print something else after that on the same line, it winds up overwriting the first part of the line. So when you print `$attQuery`, it prints this:

```
29a6966f-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407[carriage return]
 asdasd
```

...but with the second line printed on top of the first, so it comes out as:

```
 asdasdf-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407
```

The solution is to either convert the file to unix format (`dos2unix` will do this if you have it), or remove the carriage return in your script. You can do it like this:

```
tokenID=$(docker exec -ti $dockerContainerID /bin/sh -c "cat /tempdir/tokenfile.txt" | tr -d '\r')
```

Comment: THIS

or, instead of tr, you can use sed

`sed -e 's/\r//g'`

Comment: @KipK Unfortunately, that's not portable; some versions of `sed` interpret `\r` as carriage return, some don't. (I mostly use macOS, which uses the `sed` implementation from FreeBSD, which doesn't interpret them. So I'm fairly sensitive to this...)

Comment: Ah fair enough, I use the `sed` version in a lot of my linux scripting here because it only runs in our environment.

Comment: tr -d '\r' solved the issue, you were right, there wre some return character destroying my string

Answer (score 0):

I think everything works as it should

```
echo TOKEN ID $tokenID             -> TOKEN ID 29a6966f-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407
echo SERVER NAME $serverName       -> SERVER NAME asdasd
echo $attQuery                     -> asdasdf-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407
echo $agentRegQuery                -> asdasdmule/bin/amc_setup -H 29a6966f-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407
```

Why do you think something is wron here?
Best regards, Georg

Comment: Have a look in the agentRegQuery.

it should be  " ./opt/mule/bin/amc_setup -H 29a6966f-fa0e-4f08-87eb-418722872d80---46407 asdasd  "